# How to simulate asset returns using student t?

Tags: distribution, asset-returns

I am currently trying to simulate an asset return using the student-t distribution, but I can't find how I should do this. I began with the Geometric Brownian motion and just changed in order that epsilon follows the student-t distribution instead of the normal distribution, but I found out that this is not the correct way, I read a lot about levy-processes, but I don't know exactly how do simulate such returns.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: In Continuous Time it may not be possible AFAIK (since sum of two Student-t increments is not necessarily Student-t), but in Discrete Time it is easy and frequently done.

Comment: Nevertheless, you could get some insights in this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/0906.4092.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You will need a 'pseudo' random number generator - most stats programming languages have them (Matlab, R, Python...). 
But GBM is defined with Normal increments $N(0,\sigma^{2}(T-t))$ so I dont think using Student's t distribution is a good idea, never seen it in any literature/applications. It is however used for instance in GARCH modelling....

***Random variates:*** 
For instance in R, you can get random variates from student distribution from the *fGarch* [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fGarch/fGarch.pdf) - rstd() function. 
In Matlab it is described [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/trnd.html)

Then you can use this as innovations in your BM or GBM motion simulation. How to do this was answered here few times [see answer here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/7125/simulation-of-gbm).

If you elaborate further, what language you are using, or even post your code attempt so far, we might be able to help more...

Comment: Thank you so much Jan Sika. I am using Matlab. I use at the moment the following code: function [S,T]  = studentt(mu, sigma, S0, nu, T, y, NSim)
%mu=drift T= number of time steps, y=number of years, NSim number of
%simulation
N=y*T;
dt=y/N;
eps=trnd(nu,N,NSim);
trend=(mu-sigma^2/2)*dt;
W=sqrt(dt)*eps;
h=trend+sigma*W;
z = cumsum([repmat(log(S0),NSim,1) h.'],2);
S=exp(z);

Comment: I thjink you should do cumsum of the W=sqrt(dt)*eps.

Then not sure what is the repmat doing, but I think you can just follow something like [this](http://www.goddardconsulting.ca/matlab-monte-carlo-assetpaths-corr.html), but just have the student distribution instead of normal in the BM generation part