# FX spot distribution with student-t returns

Tags: fx, distribution, lognormal, spot-rate

If I am modelling my returns as $\sim N(0, \sigma^2)$, then I can evolve my spot distribution as: $$S_{t} = S_{0}e^{(\mu - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^{2})t + \sigma dW_{t}}$$
where $S_{0}$ is the spot, $\mu$ is the mean , and $\sigma$ is the returns volatility and $dW_{t}$ is the gaussian noise.

How should I amend my Spot (lognormal) distribution if I assuming my returns follow a student-t distribution $\sim t-dist(\nu)$

Thanks

Comment: Hi, this is a nice question. What do you think about changing the title to "return distribution with ..." ? And could you also make a reference to your desired application, e.g. derivatives valuation, asset allocation, ... ? Depending on the application, there may (not) exist a solution at all...

Comment: Nevertheless, you could find some ideas in here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0906.4092.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. Theory**

The Student $t$ distribution does not exhibit a moment generating function

$$
M_X(t)=\mathbb{E}\left(e^{tX} \right)
$$
Hence, there exist no closed form solution for $M_X(t=1)=\mathbb{E}\left(e^X\right)$, i.e. the expected future spot price. Thus, at least theoretically, we are not able to pinpoint the expectation of the future asset value, thereby preventing us from finding a martingal representation.

**2. Practical simulation**
Depending on your application (derivatives pricing, asset allocation), you can of course resort to some arcane methods. I understand that you know how to simulate from a $t$ distribution. Then, in order to properly centre your random variates $x\sim e^{t(\nu)}$, you could empirically re-scale your draws as $\tilde{x}=\frac{x}{\bar{e^x}}$. Again, that will not help you with theory-building, though...

HTH?

Comment: Thanks. Wanted to understand a few things (This exercise is to understand the "range" of the FX spot price over a time horizon [t,T] )... 1. If I already have a term-structure of fwd volatility , say \sigma(t), \sigma(t+1)....\ sigma(T) of the returns (fitted using a garch(p,q) model with student-t distribution assumption), how can I use those to come up with a spot price "range" over that period?

Comment: aren't the moments of the t-distribution calculable for a certain range of degrees of freedom $\nu$

Comment: You could come up with quantiles (say from 5% to 95%) of the return distribution and transform those into a price quantiles - and thereby obtain a range. would that help?

Comment: @develarist The moments, yes. But The MGF itself does not exist, hence the expectation $\mathbb{E}\left(e^{X}\right)$ does not exist. Put differently: The (non-)existence of a MGF does not imply the (non-)existence of moments.

Comment: @Kermittfrog If I fit a parametric distribution, such as the t-distribution, to the histogram of an empirical dataset's samples (using MLE of the parameters), why doesn't the parametric distribution's moments ($\mu, \sigma$) not match the empirical data's moments? If I can't even get the moments to match, doesn't this defeat the whole purpose of modeling real data parametrically

Comment: @develarist I think I have not gotten the point across. You can, of course, model returns as student-t-distributed (or whatever). I am saying that the expectation of $exp(x)$ does not exist. The expectations of $x$, $x^2$ and so on do exist up to order $\nu$. Thus, you can only 'calculate' the expectation of $exp(x)$ up to order $\nu$ (e.g. by using a taylor series approximation or such..)

Comment: sorry my question was independent of the previous comments. do you know of why it might be that the *sample estimates* of the moments of the parametric and empirical distributions don't match when they should

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116851/discussion-between-kermittfrog-and-develarist).

Comment: @Kermittfrog - so if I were to do a simulation, referring to https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/7125/simulation-of-gbm, if I understand correctly, your point was that the expectation doesn't exist(in closed form) like we have for GBM. So should we be replacing the expectation with some empirical : \mu = avg(x) ? The vol & innovations will be \sigma(t+dt)*t(\nu). Have I got that correct?

Comment: @sumit_uk1 That **could** be an approach, but I would not recommend doing that, to be honest. You could give it a try and have a look at the simulation results (quantiles, residuals etc.) and wonder whether or not they are in accordance with your expectations...

Comment: If you want an estimate of the spot range over a given time horizon, why not just use implied vols? Surely GARCH is just going to assume vol mean reverts whereas options prices do not (and will also account for event risks over the relevant period).

Comment: just an update on this... drawing rv from fitted student-t  to returns and then simulating and converting back to price space, gives very noisy ranges (as compared to a closed-form GBM). So unless I am doing something wrong here, I will just stick with GBM for now. @user42108 - are you suggesting taking the 3m atm implied vols and converting those to daily (as I need to rescale to daily range predictions)?

Comment: Whatever expiries you're interested in. If you want the next day's range, just use O/N vols. IV rather than GARCH might produce more accurate forecasts with less effort.